# Flattening the sub-lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to flatten the sub-lists within a list?

Transform

```
{{{1, x}}, {{2, x}}, {{3, x}}, {{4, x}}, {{5, x}}, {{6, x}}, {{7, x}}, {{8, x}}, {{9, x}}, {{10, x}}}
```

Into

```
{{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}, {5, x}, {6, x}, {7, x}, {8, x}, {9, x}, {10, x}}
```

I know I can do

```
Flatten /@ {{{1, x}}, {{2, x}}, {{3, x}}, {{4, x}}, {{5, x}}, {{6, x}}, {{7, x}}, {{8, x}}, {{9, x}}, {{10, x}}}
```

I am wondering whether there are some dedicated functions for such sub-list flattening?

Comment: try `Flatten[list,1]`

Comment: One can also consider using `Join @@ yourlist`.

Answer (score 7):

You are doing redundant step with [`/@`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) can make this directly:

```
Flatten[{{{1, x}}, {{2, x}}, {{3, x}}, {{4, x}}, {{5, 
    x}}, {{6, x}}, {{7, x}}, {{8, x}}, {{9, x}}, {{10, x}}}, 1]
(* {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}, {5, x}, {6, x}, {7, x}, {8, 
  x}, {9, x}, {10, x}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a built-in function for what you want to do.

```
data = {{{1, x}}, {{2, x}}, {{3, x}}, {{4, x}}, {{5, x}}, {{6, x}}, {{7, x}}, {{8, x}}, {{9, x}}, {{10, x}}};
Catenate @ data
```

> ```
> {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}, {5, x}, {6, x}, {7, x}, {8, x}, {9, x}, {10, x}}
> ```